# Remainder with no integer number in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I need to know the remainder of a division:

```
(remainder (/ 3 2) 2)
```

But as (/ 3 2) is not integer gives me an error.

modulo: contract violation 
expected: integer? 
given: 1.5 
argument position: 1st

How could I solve it?

Comment: is `(- 1.5 (truncate 1.5))` what you want?

Comment: @WillNess i need I need to see if that number is even or not, so I need the rest to see if it is divisible by 2 and also verify that it is even or is odd otherwise.

Comment: I found how to do it is with commands even? , odd? .  I did not know who came implemented. Thank you anyway @WillNess

Answer (score 4):

Aren't you just looking for

```
(remainder 3 2)
```

?

Comment: i need I need to see if that number is even or not, so I need the rest to see if it is divisible by 2 and also verify that it is even or is odd otherwise. But I found how to do it is with commands even? , odd? .  I did not know who came implemented. Thank you anyway

Comment: @Jac Here's one possible way to define `even?`: `(define (even? x) (zero? (remainder x 2)))`. Here's one possible way to define `odd?`: `(define (odd? x) (not (even? x)))`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get back a float, one of the operands needs to be a float, e.g. `(/ 3.0 2) => 1.5`.

If you can't change the numbers inside the division, you can use `exact->inexact`.

`(exact->inexact (/ 3 2)) => 1.5`

---

If you're trying to get the remainder, have you thought about the [`modulo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator?

Modulo is basically the number 'left over', or the overflow.

```
(modulo 3 2)
=> 1
(modulo 3 1)
=> 0
```

Comment: But the problem is that I need to do it with numbers that are not integers. For example: (modulo (/ 3 2) 2) @Leroy

Comment: If i do this (modulo (exact->inexact(/ 3 2)) 2) or this (modulo (/ 3.0 2) 2) gives me the same error: modulo: contract violation
expected: integer?
given: 1.5
argument position: 1st
@Leroy

Comment: @Jac R6RS has `flmod`.

Answer (score 2):

To determine whether a number is even or not, use `even?`.

An integer is even if the remainder is zero, when the number is divided by 2.

A non-integer is not even.

```
(define (my-even? x)
  (if (integer? x)
      (= (remainder x 2) 0)
      #f)))
```

The builtin functions is called `even?`.

```
> (even? 5)
#f
```